# How to deploy the 2 xap packages of same App in windows phone emulator

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to deploy the two different XAP of different solutions in my emulator. but when i deploy the xap, the last xap created is removed and the new xap is loaded. Is it because i have kept the same name of both the projects.

Please help if anyone knows how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably both Apps have the same [Product-ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). So you should change one of them.

You can change ProductID -> Packaging in WMAppManifest.xml

Later, while you will be publishing your App then the new Product-ID will be created by the Store, so you can change it for your own test.